# How can I establish connection between a client and a server where the server sends new messages to the client?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I need to establish connection between a client and a server via PHP websocket.

The server will need to keeps checking with an external API for new messages and send them to the client.

I would like to understand the concept so I can code it. I have some questions to help me wrap it around my head.

**The Client Side**
Do I keep making calls to the server via the websocket every second using javascript's `setInterval()` function or do I only make one call? How does the client know that the server have new messages?

**The Server Side**
Do I create a script the runs an infinite loop to keep checking with the API and echo the results?

**Websocket** How does the websocket know which connection a message belong to?

I am not sure if it matter but I am going to use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) for creating the websocket

Comment: It looks like they have  a pretty good tutorial on getting started, maybe start there: http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world

Comment: @Rasclatt I actually read that tutorial and applied it, it does not explain the concept. I was able to write the chat app where 2 dos terminal were sending messaging to each other "chating" but it does not tell me how to build an external check to an API and report back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

On the past days, i solved that problem via Comet. And i used Php,Node.js. You should check comet technology and look up php and NOde.js.

http://www.screenr.com/SNH

http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/2010/08/27/comet-with-nginx-and-jquery/

etc.

Comment: This approach explained in the video did not work for me as it create a new TCP connection every call which is setting some type of dos attack on your own server. In fact it caused me a big problem as the server kept reaching the max TCP connection allowed. This is why I want to use Websocket.

Comment: http://gonzalo123.com/2011/03/14/real-time-notifications-with-php/ maybe you can look that link

Answer (score 0):

**Client side:**

No.  You're connected.  There is no polling to perform.  (This is the prime advantage and purpose of WebSockets.)

When the server sends a message to the client, the client will fire the `onmessage` callback.

**Server side:**

Yes, you can set up an infinite loop that will re-check your API at a set interval.  You can also have a "dummy" WebSocket client that will send a message to your main WS server when there is new information available.  You can also use process signals.  You can also set up an open socket between your API endpoint that will notify your server on updates.  You can set your API to push information at your server.  There are also several dozens of other methods of getting information from side channels, and enumerating them (much less going into detail into any one method) is well beyond the scope of this question.

Researching, understanding the benefits and restrictions of each method, and implementing the best method are why you get paid the big bucks and are deferred to as the subject matter expert.

**How the WS server knows which client is connected**

PHP sockets use a handle -- an opaque value that in PHP happens to be an integer, but should never be treated as anything other than a signpost saying where to send messages to.  As long as your application is tracking this value (and I believe that Ratchet does some of the heavy lifting for you, in this regard) and it remains associated with your user object, you should be good.